# Changing the default port without editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: ssh, configuration, sshd

The standard way to change ports, of course, is to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.   Since I'd really like to avoid messing with the vanilla ubuntu to the greatest extent possible,I'd prefer if it is possible to change the port by putting a Port line in, for example, `~/.ssh/config`.    I've tried doing this, but to no avail.   I've also tried putting a customized copy of `sshd_config` in that directory, which also didn't work.      Can anybody suggest some way to change ports without touching any files owned by `root`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a different port on another server?  Or are you trying to change the port on your computer that happens to be a ssh server as well?  The `sshd_config` deals with the server side and the `.ssh/config` deals with the client side.

Comment: It's the server side that matters for me.    I have a few machines on the same LAN, and I ssh back and forth between them, each has it's own port, hopefully adding a security layer.    It sounds like I don't have any choice but to mess with the /etc directory?    I've had bad experiences whenever I play root.